# Getting overload selection right with template template params and enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I've got a template function in VS2013 designed to perform a "deep copy" of whatever object given to it.  One overload is for trivial types just calls operator=.  But I also have an overload designed to work for vectors of shared_ptr to my own Shape-class objects, which can only be duplicated by calling a clone() member function.

```
struct Shape { virtual std::shared_ptr<Shape> clone() const = 0; };
struct Rectangle : public Shape { virtual std::shared_ptr<Shape> clone() const override; };
```

So I've got this overload and the compiler chooses it just fine

```
template<class SHP> 
inline std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SHP>> deep_copy(
    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SHP>>& val,    
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Shape, SHP>::value>::type** = nullptr)
{
    // ... blah blah blah
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Rectangle>> objects;
auto objects2 = deep_copy(objects);
```

Then I wanted to change this to take ANY non-keyed collection (e.g. list) of shared_ptr.  OK, no problem, I actually managed that...

```
template<class COLL> 
inline COLL deep_copy(const COLL& val,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Shape, typename COLL::value_type::element_type>::value>::type** = nullptr)
```

But this syntax doesn't *really* ensure that the collection contains shared_ptr.  It merely ensures that its value_type has a nested element_type that is some sort of Shape

So my question is, ***What would be the syntax for ensuring that the contents of the collection are actually std::shared_ptr to something derived from Shape?***

I've made serveral attempts at this using template template parameters but I keep screwing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with a concept for testing if a `T` is a `shared_ptr`:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_shared_ptr : std::false_type{};

template<typename T>
struct is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> : std::true_type{};
```

Now something like

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<Shape>>::value << std::endl;
```

Will output

> true

Next, if something gives a `true_type` as a result of using that concept, we'd want to next check its `element type`:

```
template<typename T>
using element_t = typename std::decay_t<T>::element_type;
```

To see if the returned type derives from `Shape`.

Let's create another helper alias to grab the `value_type` off a collection:

```
template<typename T>
using collection_vt = typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type;
```

And now we can combine these concepts into one really gross looking one:

```
template<template<class...> class C, typename U, typename... A>
auto DoTheThing(const C<U, A...>& _collection) -> std::enable_if_t<
is_shared_ptr<collection_vt<decltype(_collection)>>::value && 
std::is_base_of<Shape, element_t<collection_vt<decltype(_collection)>>>::value
>
{
    std::cout << _collection.size() << std::endl;
}
```

The initial template arguments are for accepting a relatively generic container. Then we use a trailing return type to first ensure that `value_type` is a `shared_ptr`, and then afterwards also check that `element_type` of the `shared_ptr` derives from `Shape`. Since, upon success, the type from `enable_if` is `void`, the return type of the function becomes void.

### [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2874055c9a4756b)

Here's the test:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> vec1; 
DoTheThing(vec1); // success

std::vector<Wrapper<Shape>> vec2;
//DoTheThing(vec2); // error

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> vec3;
//DoTheThing(vec3); // error

std::list<std::shared_ptr<Shape>> vec4;
DoTheThing(vec4); // success
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this.  I'll digest this and try it. I didn't mention I ***also*** have to build with VS2012 (so no variadic templates for me) but I can work around it.

Funny, I've already been defining my own predicates (e.g. "if_shape") so I can't believe it never occurred to me to define one for "is_shared_ptr".

Just to check: This is SFINAE-friendly in the presence of other overloads, yes?  I've another working, enable_if-ed overload for just one shared_ptr<Shape>.  Want to be sure that calling that one will cause the compiler to discard this one, not complain.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. If you have an overload that matches the input type exactly, then that should be selected.